# Installing Wordpress Plugin from uploaded file require FTP logging

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the wordpress plugging but just can't bypass this FTP credential page.

I have tried:
1, add FS_METHOD: 'direct' to wp-config.php
2, change permission on the file folder, see blow,

Still just can't have it working, please help
[image]

```html
:/var/www/html/wordpressblog# ls -la
total 196
drwxr-xr-x  5 nobody nogroup  4096 Jan 15 08:43 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody nogroup  4096 Jan 15 07:36 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup   418 Sep 25  2013 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup 19935 Jan  3  2017 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  7413 Dec 12  2016 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  5434 Sep 23 20:21 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 nobody nogroup  4096 Nov 30 03:06 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup   364 Dec 19  2015 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  1627 Aug 29  2016 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  2901 Jan 15 08:43 wp-config.php
drwxrwxrwx  4 nobody nogroup  4096 Nov 30 03:06 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  3669 Aug 20 12:37 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 18 nobody nogroup 12288 Nov 30 03:06 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  2422 Nov 21  2016 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  3306 Aug 22 19:52 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup 36583 Oct 13 10:10 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  8048 Jan 11  2017 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup 16246 Oct  4 08:20 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup 30071 Oct 19 01:36 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  4620 Oct 24 06:12 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  3065 Sep  1  2016 xmlrpc.php
```

```html
/var/www# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root    4096 Jan 10 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root   root    4096 Jan 10 10:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody nogroup 4096 Jan 15 07:36 html
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wp-content` directory needs to be owned by the same user and group than the webserver. You might need to change these settings, e.g. in the httpd.conf if you are using apache

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this before when I setup my own web server using nginx. The whole /var/www/html folder and all descendants need to be owned by the same user running nginx worker to enable install plugin without ftp inside wordpress dashboard for my case. Hope it helps!